# Не видит UnitTest C# , просто пропускает и рисует синим

Tags: c#, visual-studio, юнит-тесты

При запуске теста просто пропускает и рисует его синим
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

использовали Moq, NUnit.Framework

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Threading.Tasks; 
using NUnit.Framework; 
using Moq; 

namespace _1laba 
{ 
    [TestFixture] 
    public class TestUnit 
    { 
        public Mock<Palindrom> mock;

        [Test] 
        public void Test1() 
        { 
            string vvod_norm = "kek"; 
            int length_text = 3; 
            ulong first_simbol = 1250; 
            mock = new Mock<Palindrom>(MockBehavior.Strict);//Стрик-если есть исключение то реагирует 
            var p1 = mock.Object; 
            mock.Setup<bool>(r => r.Angl(vvod_norm, first_simbol)).Returns(true);//когда вызываем ,вызывается парсер ,возвращае тру(типо срабатывают) 
            mock.Setup<bool>(r => r.Dlina(vvod_norm, length_text)).Returns(true); 
            var actual = p1.proverka(vvod_norm); 
            bool otvet = true; 
            Assert.AreEqual(otvet, actual); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Просто пропускает тест.

Comment: Если ни один тест не запускается - покажите содержимое файла csproj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Файл csproj должен быть примерно таким:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.7.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.17.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

В сети есть множество описаний какие условия должны быть выполнены для того, чтобы работало. Тут важно, чтобы тип проекта был netcoreapp а не netstandard (иначе выдаст ошибку), важны адаптеры, важен test.sdk.

И начните с малого. Поставьте самый простой тест и убедитесь что он запускается

```
namespace _1laba 
{ 
    public class TestUnit 
    { 
        [Test] 
        public void Test1() 
        { 
            Assert.AreEqual(42, 42); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Атрибут TestFixture не обязателен кстати.

Comment: спасибо, попробую